# How to cast a database entry to String

Tags: c#, database

```
 if((string)row["ProductID"].ToString() == txtBarcode.Text)
```

I want to search a row if the value of the txtbox is the same as my datatable but i have an error.. it says that `Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to string`. i just use `.ToString()` and `Convert.ToString()` but still have that error.

Comment: remove explicit cast `(string)` if you are using `ToString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note :** if you are comparing with `TextBox` value then it is better to `trim` the values before comparing to remove the whitespaces using `Trim()` method.

**Solution 1:** if you want to find the excat match then you need to use `Equals()` method.

```
if(row["ProductID"].ToString().Equals(txtBarcode.Text.Trim())
{

/* do something*/

}
```

**Solution 2:** if you want to find the part of the string then you can use `String.Contains()` method as below:

```
if(row["ProductID"].ToString().Contains(txtBarcode.Text.Trim())
{

/* do something*/

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `.ToString()` is converting the row value to a string, so you don't also need to cast it on the left with `(string)`

Ie. `if(row["ProductID"].ToString() == txtBarcode.Text)`

Personally, I'd stare clear of using == operator with anything but ints, chars and whether this instance is that instance.

A better way of comparing strings is to use `string.Equals(string)` `string.contains(string)` or `string.indexOf(string)`

Comment: In his case, String.Equals would be a better choice.

Comment: `String.Contains(String)` and `String.IndexOf(String)` are clearly wrong advices, as they return positive results in case of `"Foo Bar".IndexOf("Foo");`. Better use `String.Equals` as @Scott suggested.

Comment: @Oybek, I do mention as general options for comparing strings. Have added string.Equals though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one of the above. Either do a cast `(string)row["ProductId"]` or `Convert.ToString(row["ProductId"])` for converting the value to string. But casting using `(string)row["ProductId"]` is likely to throw `InvalidCastException`. So may be `ToString()` would be better.